# How to decrease component size with screen size like amazon website?

Tags: css

[This is a full-screen view of the amazon website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlvkM.jpg)
[This is responsive view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv8Je.png)
I want to do like this how can I do that using CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can use css media queries to manipulate the layout of the website.

[reference link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u for using bootstrap. It's easier way to learn responsive website

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

After that, u can build miniproject to learn it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).